# Server action being called twice in setState callback

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I have a nextjs event handler function that is intended to increment a value that is reflected in a component and also update the backend with the new value.

```
const [numLemons, setNumLemons] = useState(initial_array);

function incrementHandler(user_id) {
  setNumLemons(prev => {
    const tempArray = [... prev];
    const changeId = tempArray.findIndex(e => e.id === user_id);
    let lemons_count = tempArray[changeId].lemons_count;
    lemons_count++;
    tempArray[changeId] = { ...tempArray[changeId], lemons_count};
    serverActionUpdateLemons(user_id, lemons_count);
    return tempArray;
  });
}
```

In the above example, incrementHandler is called by a button press and passes in a user id I want to increment lemons for.
What I am observing is that the serverActionUpdateLemons is being called twice. I understand this is being called twice because of StrictMode, but how would I stop this happening ?

Comment: I would suggest using a useRef hook instead. So const numLemons = useRef(0);

Then in your function, go numLemons.current ++. Then have a useEffect hook that listens to numLemons and updates a display state value. That way it still updates with rerenders, but rerenders don't cause value changes.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/reactStrictMode - didn't you see this in the doc? I've spent 5 seconds to google it out. Or didn't it help?

Comment: Yes I saw that, but the docs also say that it shouldn’t matter if the code is correctly written. It mentions a “pure function”. What I’m really looking for is how to restructure my code so that it is a pure function.